# Set a StructureMap Nested Container to resolve unique object instances by default

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, structuremap, structuremap3

According to [StructureMap's documentation](http://structuremap.github.io/object-lifecycle/supported-lifecycles/#transient) the default behavior of containers is that a Parent Container resolves a new object instance each time one is requested and Nested Containers resolve the same object instance.

In 99% of cases this is fine - however I'm keen to know if there's a way I can set a nested container to behave similarly to the Parent Container and resolve new object instances by default - without the need to rely on the `.AlwaysUnique()` method.

Is this possible or is `.AlwaysUnique` the only way to do it on an object by object basis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that beside explicit specification of nested container configuration there is no support for that as it was designed around creating temporary context for objects resolution. IIRC in SM 3.0 *HttpContextScoped* lifecycle was implemented with usage of nested container.

If you want to have the flexibility of resolving existing object from the container or creating a new one you can implement factory that would handle it for you through injected context into the factory or based on explicit method call (`factory.Create()` or `factory.ReuseIfExistsOrCreate()`).

Hope this helps!

Comment: I think you're right. I've not been able to find anything that supports that it can be done.